# How to Configure Network Tracing Dotnet core for HttpClient calls?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, .net-standard, system.diagnostics

As per reference document at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-configure-network-tracing

We can setup this in web.config or any other configuration file and we get detailed system.net traces, packets traces for `HttpClient` calls and any kind of issue in `HttpClient` calls can be captured in traces, be it certificate, TLS or anything else.

However, do we have similar implementation for dotnet core / standard which can be used in both web app or console app/ libraries ?

Configuration for dotnet framwork :

```
<configuration>  
  <system.diagnostics>  
    <sources>  
      <source name="System.Net" tracemode="includehex" maxdatasize="1024">  
        <listeners>  
          <add name="System.Net"/>  
        </listeners>  
      </source>  
      --------------
----------------------
```

Comment: I have the same problem.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#tracesource-provider suggests to me this might not be possible on core.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/29210

Answer (score 6):

.NET (Core) uses [EventSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#event-source) to record these events. On Windows the event source uses [Event Tracing for Windows (ETW)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/etw/about-event-tracing) so all tools that work with it can be used to record and read through the trace output. On Linux, [LTTNG](https://web.archive.org/web/20191208123333/http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2017/03/30/tracing-runtime-events-in-net-core-on-linux/) is used to record the events.

Microsoft's runtime repository [contains documentation for Windows](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/workflow/debugging/libraries/windows-instructions.md) on how to debug network traces using both [PerfView](https://github.com/microsoft/perfview) and [logman](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/logman). There's also [documentation on capturing traces on Linux](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/project/linux-performance-tracing.md) that is useful.

Microsoft is working on unifying the experience across platforms in a way. At the moment this support seems to be happening through the [dotnet-trace command](https://github.com/dotnet/diagnostics/blob/master/documentation/dotnet-trace-instructions.md).

You didn't mention ASP.NET Core directly, so I will presume your question isn't specific to it, but note that as Alexandre pointed out, [tracing can be configured](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/logging-tracing) and may provide some or all of what you need.

Comment: The community project `dotnet-wtrace` might be a better alternative when coming to network specific tracing, https://github.com/lowleveldesign/dotnet-wtrace

Answer (score -3):

Everything is explained in the documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2#logging-1.

In summary, you need to setup "Trace" logging level in appsettings.json and you should see the logs (if you register the HttpClient like this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2#basic-usage) :

```
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Trace"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi , Thanks for reference , but those logs are more of request logs , while the network traces which are available for  dotnet framework are very detailed traces including Application , TCP etc layers containing , handshake , certificate ,TLS and all other things.

Comment: Hum, I don't know if it's actually possible with .NET Core I didn't find any references of that.