# VS Community - VB - Unable to read to or write from app.config via Settings dialog

Tags: vb.net, app-config

Recently [I posted a couple of errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66712029/app-config-error-in-vb-project-in-vs-community) I was having, relating to app.config in a VB project. Andrew Morton kindly pointed me to an [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63685246/1115360) which resolved the first part of the issue, but I've since found that I still can't add/update variables in app.config via the Settings dialog in the project properties, nor can the Settings dialog read the app.config file.

The error message is:

> an error occurred while reading the app.config file. the file might be corrupted

If I manually change the variable in app.config the program I'm coding still finds the old value as it's taking it from Settings.Designer.vb, and that's not getting updated when I change the variable in Settings as the platform isn't reading the app.config.

I've (again) run the app.config through an XML checker, all fine. I read one solution for this issue, which suggested the cause can be duplicate elements in the 'sectionGroup' area of app.config, but mine doesn't appear to have duplicate elements (app.config posted).

Steps I have tried are:

1. Removed and re-added the project from the solution.
2. Updated VS.
3. Repaired VS.
4. Deleted the app.config file and the variables from the Project Properties - System dialog, then added a new app.config and recreated the variables in the System dialog.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="system.diagnostics" type="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfigurationHandler"/>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" >
            <section name="Doghunter.My.MySettings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <!-- This section defines the logging configuration for My.Application.Log -->
            <source name="DefaultSource" switchName="DefaultSwitch">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="FileLog"/>
                    <!-- Uncomment the below section to write to the Application Event Log -->
                    <!--<add name="EventLog"/>-->
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
        <switches>
            <add name="DefaultSwitch" value="Information" />
        </switches>
        <sharedListeners>
            <add name="FileLog"
                 type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener, Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL"
                 initializeData="FileLogWriter"/>
            <!-- Uncomment the below section and replace APPLICATION_NAME with the name of your application to write to the Application Event Log -->
            <add name="EventLog" type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener" initializeData="Doghunter"/>
        </sharedListeners>
    </system.diagnostics>
    <applicationSettings>
        <Doghunter.My.MySettings>
            <setting name="TestKey" serializeAs="String">
                <value>Henry</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="NewKey" serializeAs="String">
                <value>Moscow</value>
            </setting>
        </Doghunter.My.MySettings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk?

Comment: Thanks - I just ran chkdsk on C:, no change unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuilding the project as a Windows Forms Application (.Net Framework 4.7.2) resolved it.
Originally chose 'plain' Windows Forms Application, which used 5.0

No idea why this is the case, but now works so all good.