# Public dictionary not visible to class

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, public, system.diagnostics

I have declared two `Public` dictionaries in a `Module` as follows :

```
Module Globals
    Public buttonImagesEnabled As Dictionary(Of Integer, Image)
    Public buttonImagesDisabled As Dictionary(Of Integer, Image)
End Module
```

Which are then initialised in the constructor for a `Form` :

```
Public Class myForm
    Public Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        buttonImagesEnabled = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Image)
        buttonImagesDisabled = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Image)
    End Sub
End Class
```

The solution builds fine but when I try to run it, I get an exception (at the line in the form constructor specifying a `New Dictionary`) :

> System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for
> 'MySolution.Globals' threw an exception.'

InnerException #1

> {"Configuration system failed to initialize"}

InnerException #2

> {"Unrecognized configuration section system.diagnostics.
> (...ProjectPath.MySolution.dll.config line 8)"}

Checked the .dll.config file and it's just a `<system.diagnostics>` XML tag (the rest of the XML looks fine to me)

If I move the `Public` declaration into the `Form` (and out of the `Module`) it runs fine ***but*** I can't access the dictionaries from any of my classes (i.e. referencing them in the classes produces errors á la :

> 'buttonImagesEnabled' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to
> its protection level.

Am I missing something blindingly obvious here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, looks like it was nothing to do with the dictionaries, nor their declarations - the `app.config` file was somehow botched.

The solution here : [.NET Core - Using system.diagnostics in App.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57078166/net-core-using-system-diagnostics-in-app-config) solved the problem (manual insertion of the `<system.diagnostics>` `configSection` into the XML)

Why on earth Visual Studio / .NET Core inserts the section, but not the declaration, automatically, is absurd to me!